# How to join 3 table and perform union in a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are four table **Bill_entry**,**Customer**,**Chit**,**Cash**. I want to join table Customer with table Bill_entry in following query where they have common column customer_id. Goal here is by using `customer_id` i want to print `customer_name` too in one query.

i have tried but couldn't get correct syntax

Initial code before including Customer table :

```
SELECT Bill_entry.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM Chit UNION SELECT * FROM Cash) as t1 RIGHT JOIN 
     entry
     ON (Bill_entry.bill_no = t1.bill_no)
WHERE t1.bill_no IS NULL
```

MY tries :

```
SELECT Bill_entry.*, Customer.customer_name
FROM ((SELECT * FROM Chit UNION SELECT * FROM Cash) as t1 RIGHT JOIN entry ON (Bill_entry.bill_no = t1.bill_no) WHERE t1.bill_no IS NULL)customer where Bill_entry.customer_id = Customer.Customer_id
```

Comment: Can you format your queries better and also See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Do `Chit` and `Cash` have the same schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in another `JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.*, cu.customer_name
FROM bill_entry e LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT * FROM Chit
      UNION ALL  -- assume you don't want to remove duplicates
      SELECT * FROM Cash
     ) c 
     entry e
     ON e.bill_no = c.bill_no LEFT JOIN
     Customer cu
     ON cu.customer_id = e.Customer_id
WHERE c.bill_no IS NULL;
```

Note some changes.

- The `UNION` --> `UNION ALL`.  I assume you don't want to remove duplicates or incur the overhead for trying to remove them.
- `RIGHT JOIN` --> `LEFT JOIN`.  It is usually much simpler to think about `LEFT JOIN`s -- keep all the rows in the first table and then matching rows in the others.
- The `JOIN` conditions are all in `ON` clauses, not the `WHERE` clause.